# Add a beamer note to a section slide using pandoc and markdown

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I am using pandoc to convert markdown to beamer slides. I am using the notes in beamer to make note slides. I have `slide-level=3` so that the first two markdown headings are sections. I want the section title frames in the presentation, and I want to be able to add a note on section slides. However, pandoc seems to put the notes into a frame. So for instance:

```
# First Section
\note{I want a note here}

## First Subsection in First Section

::: notes

Using this also does not work

:::

### First Slide
```

produces the following LaTeX code from pandoc:

```
\hypertarget{first-section}{%
\section{First Section}\label{first-section}}
 
\begin{frame}{First Section}
\note{I want a note here}
\end{frame}

\hypertarget{first-subsection-in-first-section}{%
\subsection{First Subsection in First Section}\label{first-subsection-in-first-section}}
\begin{frame}{First Subsection in First Section}
\note{Using this also does not work}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{First slide}
\protect\hypertarget{first-slide}{}
```

This adds a blank slide after the section slides that then have the note. This is not what I want. If I go into the `tex` code and delete the frames, the output pdf is what I want (which means that beamer can handle notes in sections without a frame slide):

```
\hypertarget{first-section}{%
\section{First Section}\label{first-section}}
 
\note{I want a note here}

\hypertarget{first-subsection-in-first-section}{%
\subsection{First Subsection in First Section}\label{first-subsection-in-first-section}}

\note{Using this also does not work}

\begin{frame}{First slide}
\protect\hypertarget{first-slide}{}
```

Unfortunately the answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199199/insert-raw-latex-between-beamer-slides-using-pandoc-markdown) only answer for that specific case, not that general question that was asked. The "hack" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647855) also inserts a frame.

Is there a way to have something passed to into the LaTeX code *without* a frame?

EDIT: Apparently this is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614387/pandoc-4317-forces-content-under-title-slides-to-be-included-in-a-frame-in-pand). But it is not the same, because I would like a general solution at any heading level above the slide level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed for the single usage of speaker notes in pandoc for beamer in [this issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7857) and [this commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/52b78b10c81e99926d560bc383938006be3b0458).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is the exact same issue as [pandoc-4317-forces-content-under-title-slides-to-be-included-in-a-frame-in-pand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614387/pandoc-4317-forces-content-under-title-slides-to-be-included-in-a-frame-in-pand). I used a specific slide level in a mere attempt to simplify my request by anchoring ideas, but `pandoc 2.7` onwards introduced the **undesired** change to satisfy the `revealjs` crowd. I find this absurd, if I please may, because the change is implemented for consistency sake (sic), but `beamer` is not meant to have 3D navigation of slides, quite the contrary, imho. It's designed to work with article mode, focusing on `.pdf` production, for which 3D slides makes zero sense. Fortunately, the offending commit is purely in the file [LaTeX.hs](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/f431f67b2f2f5071345fa5800658375afaf44c1b), leading to an easy solution...

Since I finally gave up on this after sending multiple emails to JGM and the `pandoc` list... what is my solution? Maybe overkill, but I simply recompile `pandoc`!! [Using the recommended `stack`](https://pandoc.org/installing.html), it's actually beyond smooth, easy, and fast in `Windows` or i would not recommend. I was totally surprised and not expecting it.

Just replace lines [233-241] in [`LaTeX.hs`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs), `commit f431f67b2f2f5071345fa5800658375afaf44c1b`, with

```
    = return $ Div (ident,"section":dclasses,dkvs) xs
```

This change produces a couple of `warnings`, so i am sure it can be improved, but ain't wasting any further time on this. The executable is produced in
`pandoc-x.x.x\.stack-work\install\d8f8683f\bin`.
I copy over to
`C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\pandoc`.
BINGO!
No more annoying unwanted slides... regardless your level. I can keep my `pandoc` version uptodate this way. Keen to hear if there's any improvement that can be made to this "hammer to kill the fly" approach.